# Kindle books on IPad

Tags: ipad

I have got some ebooks that I want to load onto my iPad in the Kindle App. I don't know how to do this and was wondering if anyone out there has any suggestions

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a recent version of the Kindle app, the simplest way is through the iTunes file sharing:  http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4094 has details on how to do it.

You can also mail books to your kindle address (if you choose the settings icon in the kindle app, you can see your "Send-to-Kindle Email Address"), and then it will sync to Amazon's cloud.

(edit)
Note that the book needs to be compatible with the Kindle app, and not DRM protected etc.

Comment: The Kindle uses .MOBI format.

Comment: @TonyWilliams, the kindle does "use" the .MOBI format, however the native format supported is: [AZW and AZW1](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200375630). For MOBI to be read it needs to be DRM free.